# Texture with alpha channel covers background objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

While implementing billboard objects to my engine i encountered a problem (screenshot below)

[image]

as you can see billboard object covers everything in background (skybox seems to be an exception). And this is not exacly how i would like it to work. I have no idea where is the problem.

my fragment shader is pretty simple:

```
#version 330

uniform sampler2D tex;

in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
    FragColor = texture2D(tex, TexCoord);
}
```

and the billboard is just triangle strip made in geometry shader.

All ideas would be nice.

Comment: try `if(color.a == 0.0) discard;` refer http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Transparent_Textures for additional info

Comment: I used a threshold idea `if(FragColor.a < 0.9) discard;` and it seems to work. To be honest it doesn't look like great solution but for now it works better than it used to

Comment: Check ["Blending can be used to make objects appear transparent. However, blending alone is not enough. There are a number of steps that you must take to make transparency work. ..."](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting)

Answer (score 2):

Probably draw order issue, you need to draw opaque objects first and then alpha blended objects back to front. Alternatively you can enabled alpha testing or in your shader discard fragments if their alpha is below a certain threshold.